# How to know the number of clients connected to each SSID from the CLI?

Tags: linux, shell-script, networking, wifi

Is there any Linux command/Bash script for a wireless client to know the number of clients connected to each WiFi SSID ? How can I do this in in a shell script? I code in Bash and my operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You probably can do it via access point for each SSID but the way is depend of its soft. So read the each manual.

Comment: I'm supposed to write a bash script for this, how can I do this ? @Costas

Comment: Can you suggest any command/instructions on how to write a bash script ? @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nmap` or the `arp-scan` command to get the connected devices on your AP

```
nmap -O IP/24
```

the `man nmap`:

> -O (Enable OS detection)
>              Enables OS detection, as discussed above. Alternatively, you can
>              use -A to enable OS detection along with other things.

```
arp-scan --interface=wlan0 IP/24
```

Or

```
arp-scan --localnet
```

[man arp-scan](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arp-scan)